# POST request in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, post, get

I want to make this below javascript call to change from GET to POST

```
function redirect() {
    if (window.focus)
        self.focus();
    this.location = "/test/DownloadReport?
     <%=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(request.getQueryString())%>";
}
```

So, I've done below -

```
function redirect() {
    if(window.focus)
        self.focus();
    loc = '/test/DownloadReport';   
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("value", "
    <%=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(request.getQueryString())%>");
    form.appendChild(input);

    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", loc);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

But issue I'm facing is when this code is getting executed then the servlet is throwing error as the `request.getQueryString()` is not proper. I'm suspecting the way I'm setting value for `request.getQueryString()` is incorrect. Could you please advise what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your POST request looks like:

```
value=foo%3Dbar%26ipsum%3Dlorem
```

Whereas your GET request looked like:

```
foo=bar&ipsum=lorem
```

What you'll likely need to do is add an `input` for each parameter in the original QueryString. This can get tricky.

So instead of:

```
<input name="value" value="foo=bar&ipsum=lorem" />
```

You need:

```
<input name="foo" value="bar" />
<input name="ipsum" value="lorem" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. request.getQueryString() gives the below output &report_id=0&id=123345&id=6789 , so I've done like this String firstId = str.substring(str.indexOf("&id=")+4,str.lastIndexOf("&id")); String secondID = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("&id")+4,str.length());  input.setAttribute("name","report_id");input.setAttribute("value", "<%=request.getParameter("report_id") %>");input.setAttribute("name", "id");input.setAttribute("value", "<%=firstId %>");
input.setAttribute("name", "id");input.setAttribute("value", "<%=secondID %>");form.appendChild(input); But no luck.whats missing?

Comment: That looks like a bad query string. `id` is in there twice. Use a proper function to parse the QueryString. I don't know if Java has a function for that but it probably does.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is improper.

ESAPI Javascript Encoder converts human readable javascript to [UTF-8](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) Escape sequence.

try the following code :

```
input.setAttribute("value", "<%=request.getQueryString()%>");
input.setAttribute("type","hidden");
```